# Laravel Microsoft Graph, how to get specific events with Carbon

Tags: php, laravel, api

I'm trying to get specific events via Microsoft Graph Api, currently I work in Laravel with https://github.com/daveismyname/laravel-microsoft-graph package.

I only want events where carboon now is between start and end dateTime.

Right now i get all events by doing this:

```
$events = Api::get('me/events');
return dd($events);
```

And return this:

[image: event return value]

Answer (score 0):

Christian you need to pass `$filter` param to Graph API

Try this

```
$start = Carbon::now()->toIso8601ZuluString();
$end = Carbon::now()->addWeek()->toIso8601ZuluString();

$url = "me/events?$filter=Start/DateTime+ge+'$start'+and+End/DateTime+lt+'$end'";

$events = Api::get($url);
```

Change the $start and $end dates to your own dates (zuluString)

Also, you can check [Microsoft graph api parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters#filter-parameter)

Comment: Hi Rob, thank you!

But even with:

        $start = Carbon::now()->toIso8601ZuluString();
        $end = Carbon::now()->add(1, 'day')->toIso8601ZuluString();


It still returns all events?

Comment: It will return Events only for given date

`+ge+` means `greater or equal` `+lt+` means `lower  . I have tested it with graph api. It is 100% working, If you didnt get expected result, check your dates, or give me your dates, I will make correct query for you